# Split based on dash and 'em dash'

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use VBA Split to tokenize a string with dashes/hyphens
The data has the Excel em-dashes in it.

Any idea how I can split them?

```
Split("This-works-fine", "-") 
Split("This–not–so–well", "-")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Split("This–not–so–well", chrw(8211))
```